# Why doesn't CSS absolute work with a static parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.) says that

> element with `position: absolute` is
> positioned relative to the nearest *positioned* ancestor. Where
> *positioned* element is one whose position is anything except static.

My question is why are `static` elements excluded?

I know that I can set

```
position: relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px
```

which is the same as `position:static`, but in my opinion, it looks like a workaround.

Comment: Because sometimes you don't want a parent, which is `static` by default, to affect an absolute positioned child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `position: relative` will do.

This is a good thing, because otherwise the browser will have to apply calculations on every element instead of being able to take shorter routes for static positioning.

It also means you can have arbitrary containers, so long as they're static, and still have an element be positionable relative to the container of your choice.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is why static elements are excluded?

Because otherwise `absolute` wouldn't be able to position with respect to anything other than the element's immediate parent.

> I know that I can set position: relative;left:0px;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px

You don't need to explicitly set the distances. Just the position property will do.